# Using RSpec to test active record scope that uses the includes method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, named-scope

Given the following two classes:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :holiday_schedule
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
  scope :with_holiday_schedule, includes(:holiday_schedule)
end

class HolidaySchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_many :locations
end
```

How would you spec the with_holiday_schedule scope to ensure that accessing location.holiday_schedule.name in a loop will not cause the N+1 Query problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After positing to the RSpec users mailing list and reading more about speccing in general, I ultimately came to the realization that this isn't worth a unit test. The :includes directive is well tested in rails and the overhead of testing that simple line is higher than the risk associated with it failing or being removed by another developer - at least in my case.

What I really care about is performance of the application. Speccing performance would be a lot more productive than jumping through hoops to unit test this line.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Counting the number of queries performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490411/counting-the-number-of-queries-performed).

This should work perfectly in your solution.
They've done this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.count_queries do
  Ticket.first
end
```

You can use it this way in your spec:

```
queries = ActiveRecord::Base.count_queries do
  location.with_holiday_schedule.holiday_schedule.name
end
queries.should_be == 1
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: I'm testing this out now. Not crazy about putting this in the ActiveRecord namespace, so I'll play with it some.

Comment: this worked for the most part. Queries would actually equal 2 (one for locations, one for all associated holiday schedules). For some reason, It would work when manually running the tests but when running them under Guard/Spork, the count would be 6. Adding my actual solution - which is kind of a cop out - below.

Comment: This can be abstracted out to an RSpec custom matcher if people aren't into the raw DSL.

https://rspec.info/documentation/3.0/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers