# Retrieving sql queries from Active-record queries in Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How do I trace which SQL query did my Activerecord methods generated (eg find, where).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5492207/498594) answer gives you a lot of control - you get access to the queries in the app itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug ActiveRecord queries from a console.

Hit `rails console` and enter:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Rails 3.0.x, you can do that by configuring your active record. Put this in `config/environments/development.rb`

```
# Log ActiveRecord
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined?
Rails::Console
```

Now, every query is explained in console.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `to_sql` on relation objects (like that returned when you call `where`) to get the SQL for those queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it permanently (always show queries in console) just add those files:

~/.rvmrc

```
railsrc_path = File.expand_path('~/.railsrc')
if ( ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || defined? Rails ) && File.exist?( railsrc_path )
  begin
    load railsrc_path
  rescue Exception
    warn "Could not load: #{ railsrc_path }" # because of $!.message
  end
end
```

~/.railsrc

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
```