# How to prepare SQL statement without using where() method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to prepare an SQL statement like that built by ActiveRecord `where()` method (using named placeholders):

```
Client.where("created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date",
{start_date: params[:start_date], end_date: params[:end_date]})
```

I have to use this in `CASE .. END` statement after `ORDER BY` clause (or in `SELECT` to create a computed column) to protect it from SQL injection.

**EDIT**:
I have to retrieve all the ActiveRecord models by this query too. So can I use `find_by_sql()`? (trying...).

**EDIT2**:
`find_by_sql()` can't use named placeholders (`:start_date` in the above code example).

It's Rails 3.2.11

**EDIT3**:
Sorry, it can use with an Array as one parameter ([find_by_sql with array format in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977104/find-by-sql-with-array-format-in-rails-3)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write / prepare anything that ActiveRecord does. Do you mean to use a direct DBI query?

I recommend you trace the SQL that ActiveRecord is generating.

[Retrieving sql queries from Active-record queries in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173448/retrieving-sql-queries-from-active-record-queries-in-rails-3)

[Tracing Rails 3 SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530870/tracing-rails-3-sql-queries)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/debugging_rails_applications.html

See query_trace for one approach.

A tutorial on how to use Ruby DBI and prepared statements:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_database_access.htm

Quoted directly from the tutorial:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require "dbi"

begin
 # connect to the MySQL server
 dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:TESTDB:localhost", 
                    "testuser", "test123")
 sth = dbh.prepare( "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME,
               LAST_NAME, 
               AGE, 
       SEX, 
       INCOME)
               VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" )
 sth.execute('John', 'Poul', 25, 'M', 2300)
 sth.execute('Zara', 'Ali', 17, 'F', 1000)
 sth.finish
 dbh.commit
 puts "Record has been created"
rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
 puts "An error occurred"
 puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"
 puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
 dbh.rollback
ensure
 # disconnect from server
 dbh.disconnect if dbh
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `find_by_sql()` solved this.

But this can't be use as scoped query. (And thus cannot be chained).