# Ruby on Rails: Get the total number of queries for an ActiveRecord connection for statistics

Tags: ruby, activerecord

What is an easy way to get the number/count of queries for an ActiveRecord connection in Ruby on Rails?

Subscribing, [as explained in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490411/counting-the-number-of-queries-performed), seems a bit complex to implement, because I only want the number of real total queries issued over the whole lifetime of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

So i did a monkeypatch initializer on my own :)

```
### Query Counter for mysql2 adapter
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class AbstractAdapter
      @@querycount = 0
      attr_reader :querycount
      def self.querycount; @@querycount; end
    end
    class Mysql2Adapter < AbstractMysqlAdapter
      def exec_query(sql, name = 'SQL', binds = [])
        @@querycount += 1
        @querycount = 0 if @querycount.nil?
        @querycount += 1
        result = execute(sql, name)
        ActiveRecord::Result.new(result.fields, result.to_a)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can then get the total querycount of all connections with

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter.querycount
```