# Rails disable database to test caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, testing, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to assert something with the assurance that it's come from the cache and didn't hit the database. I tried this:

```
assert_equal 29, Article.sum # assume this is DB-intensive
Article.clear_all_connections!
assert_equal 29, Article.sum # cached result
```

But the connection is re-established automatically, so `clear_all_connections!` serves no purpose here. How to cut the cord to the database? And do so temporarily, so that it can be resumed later in the test.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and more general solution turns out to be [counting the number of queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29968289/18706). To ensure everything is from cache, just assert the counter is zero during some operation.